# Google Translate API ignores accented characters

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api

It appears the Google Translate API (I'm using V3 with the default model) ignores accents, treating accented characters the same as non-accented, i.e. for Spanish:

```
habló = I speak  (should be "I spoke")
hablo = I speak  (correct)
```

This appears to be a fundamental problem, not just a few cases of mistranslation.

Comment: I have the same problem. I inspect the content input and the api removes every special character as accents or ¿ I dont know why